# python unicode replace MemoryError

Tags: python

i want replace unicode character to a file with python

this is my code :

```
with codecs.open('/etc/bluetooth/main.conf', "r", "utf8") as fi:
            mainconf=fi.read()
        forrep = ''.decode('utf8')
        for line in mainconf.splitlines():
            if('Name = ' in line):
                forrep = line.split('=')[1]
        print 'name',type(name)
        print 'mainconf',type(mainconf)
        print 'forrep',type(forrep)
        mainconf = mainconf.replace(forrep, name)
        #mainconf = mainconf.replace(forrep.decode('utf8'),' '+name)
        with codecs.open('/etc/bluetooth/main.conf','w',"utf8") as fi:
            fi.write(mainconf)
```

but python always get me error `MemoryError`...

this out :

```
name <type 'unicode'>
mainconf <type 'unicode'>
forrep <type 'unicode'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WORK/Bluetooth/Bluetooth.py", line 359, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__':main()
  File "WORK/Bluetooth/Bluetooth.py", line 336, in main
    BLMan.SetAllHCIName(common.cfg.get('BLUETOOTH', 'HCI_DEVICE_NAME'))
  File "WORK/Bluetooth/Bluetooth.py", line 194, in SetAllHCIName
    mainconf = mainconf.replace(forrep, name)
MemoryError
```

Comment: open file read and write mode at first line and write to this.

Comment: How big is `main.conf`? What platform are you on?

Comment: As a side note: What is the `forrep = ''.decode('utf8')` for? All that's going to do is create the empty unicode string `u''`, which (a) you could just write as a literal, and (b) you don't use anywhere. I'm a bit worried that you're expecting that `decode` to somehow be remembered and automatically re-applied any time you store anything to the name `forrep` later or something, which it won't be.

Comment: Also, I suspect you want `if line.startswith('Name = '):` or `if line.lstrip().startswth('Name =')`, so that if the substring `'Name ='` happens to appear in a _value_ somewhere, it won't get matched, only if the _key_ is `Name`.

Comment: @abarnert main.conf is small file , about 30 lines ...
i don't understand ... please correct my code and write here ... tnx

Comment: "please correct my code and write here" isn't how this site works. You have to (a) answer the questions we asked in comments (like "What platform are you on?"), and (b) read, try to understand, and ask questions about answers people gave you like Padraic's. If you want someone to just do all the work for you, go hire someone.

Comment: Meanwhile, it would help if you printed the _length_ of the three strings, instead of their types (which we already can guess are going to be `unicode`…).

Comment: Also where is name coming from?

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the file object, you are storing the whole file content in memory using `mainconf=fi.read()` :

```
with codecs.open('/etc/bluetooth/main.conf', "r", "utf8") as fi:
    for line in fi:
```

You store all the lines with read then you store a list of all the lines using splitlines so you are storing all the file content twice and as @abarnet pointed out in a comment you then try to store a third copy with
 `mainconf = mainconf.replace(forrep, name)`.

Iterating over the file object will give you a line at a time, if you need to store the lines after replacing do so each time through the loop so at most you will only have one copy of the file content in memory.

I have no idea what name is but writing to a tempfile will be the most efficient way to do what you want:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

with open('/etc/bluetooth/main.conf') as fi, NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".", delete=False) as out:
    for line in fi:
        if line.startswith("Name ="):
            a, b = line.split("=",1)
            out.write("{} = {}".format(a, name.encode("utf-8")))
        else:
            out.write(line)

move(out.name, '/etc/bluetooth/main.conf')
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but notice that he wants to overwrite the file at the end. So, he needs a bit more. Probably opening a temporary file, writing line by line as he reads line by line, and then moving the temporary file over the original.

Comment: @abarnert, True a  NamedTempFile should work or maybe use fileinput.input. The OP is actually storing the contents twice which does not help either

Comment: Yea, `NamedTempfile` is perfect, except it's a bit of a pain to wrap it in the `codecs` module. (If this is Python 2.6+, he could use `io` instead of `codecs`, though…)

Comment: @abarnert, I am not sure that codecs is even necessary. I will wait until the OP replies to some comments before deciding what the best approach is.

Comment: Actually, he's not just creating two copies of the content, he's creating _another_ copy by doing `mainconf = mainconf.replace(forrep, name)` instead of just doing the replace on the line that needs it.

Comment: @abarnert, good spot,  If the OP can store two copies and only gets a memory error on the third then  the code may well work as is by just keeping one copy.

Comment: Then again, that "fix" may only work until he adds one line to the file, so doing it the right way, as in your answer, is still almost certainly worth it…